# Can I apply again for a student visa and what are the chances?

Tags: usa, student-visa, refusal

[image]I had an interview about 2 years back for the student visa for the USA from Nepal. At the time I trusted the consultancy and it gave me the I-20 telling me that I am admitted to the college and went to the embassy for the interview. There I found out that the I-20 was fake and they interrogated me and the consular officer told me not to apply again. Does that mean I am permanently banned?

Comment: Did the consular officer give you a letter or mark your passport?

Comment: Not specific marks. But I was given a letter of causes of rejection as everyone gets after being rejected for student visa. But no specific marks on my passport just the appointment date at the cover of my passport.

Comment: Could you post the letter with your personal details blanked out? You can do it as an edit to your original question

Comment: In this comment section?? If okay in this section I can.

Comment: Migrating this to Expats.

Comment: There is nothing in the page shown to say you cannot apply again. Are there other pages?

Comment: Its poor practice to paste the same question in two different forums .. same question https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/13006/can-i-apply-again-for-a-student-visa-after-a-refusal/13007#13007

Comment: No they gave me this single paper only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are very fortunate. The immigration officer ruled your application ineligible and denied your visa but they did not flag it for fraud and they did not ban you.

1. Ineligible is the same as denied: https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/visa-information-resources/visa-denials.html
2. You are free to reapply at any time however you do have to say a prior visa application was denied
3. Once you have a denial on your record, future applications get scrutinized much more so you should make sure your next application is faultless.
4. Do not trust local agencies consultancies that arrange both the school and the visa. They are often fraudulent as you have found out.

Comment: INA 214(b) is not a banned?? I really appreciate your effort sir.

Comment: That’s why I think they dodged a bullet. They were found ineligible and normally they would be banned but the letter itself says they may reapply. The OP should keep the letter so that they can use it to show they were in fact not banned.

Comment: OP?? Meaning that I am free to apply but not banned. And I will be scrutinized??